# What's the meaning of "into frame" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following are comments made on [this video link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpQKF.gif)]:

Person A:

> Anyone know if the dude actually lost any digits? A fish that big looks like it could take off with your arm if it wanted to.

Person B:

> I don't see any spurting blood when his hand flashes back into frame so he's probably fine.

What does Person B meant when he says *when his hand flashes back into frame*?
I understand that *flash* here means *to move very quickly* according to [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/flash), but what about *into frame*? Does *frame* here talking about the body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, I presume *into frame* is short for *into the picture frame*.

In other words:

> I don't see any spurting blood when his hand flashes back into the picture frame, so he's probably fine.

Person B is saying that, if the injury was serious, we'd probably see some blood in the picture.

Comment: Exactly. In cinema/video production *frame*, noun, means both the individual image and the physical area it represents, and *frame*, verb (or *frame up*) means to set the camera in a manner which will locate the objects captured at a specific location within the *frame*, noun.

Comment: +1 to StonyB's comment. In particular, "back into frame" simply means "is visible in the field of view of the camera again".